# How to remove duplicates in set for objects?

Tags: python

I have set of objects:

```
class Test(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.i = random.randint(1,10)


res = set()

for i in range(0,1000):
    res.add(Test())

print len(res) = 1000
```

How to remove duplicates from set of objects ?

Thanks for answers, it's work:

```
class Test(object):
    def __init__(self, i):
        self.i = i
    #   self.i = random.randint(1,10)
    #   self.j = random.randint(1,20)

    def __keys(self):
        t = ()
        for key in self.__dict__:
            t = t + (self.__dict__[key],)
        return t

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return isinstance(other, Test) and self.__keys() == other.__keys()

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.__keys())

res = set()

res.add(Test(2))
...
res.add(Test(8))
```

result: [2,8,3,4,5,6,7]

but how to save order ? Sets not support order. Can i use list instead set for example ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your objects must be *[hashable](http://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-hashable)* (i.e. must have [`__eq__()`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__) and [`__hash__()`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__) defined) for sets to work properly with them:

```
class Test(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.i = random.randint(1, 10)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.i == other.i

    def __hash__(self):
        return self.i
```

> An object is hashable if it has a hash value which never changes during its lifetime (it needs a `__hash__()` method), and can be compared to other objects (it needs an `__eq__()` or `__cmp__()` method). Hashable objects which compare equal must have the same hash value.
>
> Hashability makes an object usable as a dictionary key and a set member, because these data structures use the hash value internally.

If you have several attributes, hash and compare a tuple of them (thanks, `delnan`):

```
class Test(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.i = random.randint(1, 10)
        self.k = random.randint(1, 10)
        self.j = random.randint(1, 10)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return (self.i, self.k, self.j) == (other.i, other.k, other.j)

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash((self.i, self.k, self.j))
```

Comment: Mix them to produce a unique integer hash (use the buitlin `hash` function on non-integer attributes and `^` them together, for example) and define equality in a way that makes sense to you. What these two objects must have in common to consider them duplicates? Express that in `__eq__`.

Comment: The easiest way to define equality and hash is to find a tuple that's isomorphic to your object, and then delegate to tuple's `__hash__` and `__eq__`, either by using `collections.namedtuple` (if applicable) or by constructing the tuples on demand: `def __hash__(self): return hash((self.x, self.y, self.z))`.

Comment: It's worth noting that by default, you already _have_ an `__eq__` and `__hash__`—but they work on object identity. In those terms, everything was technically already working, because there were no duplicate objects in the set, just "similar" objects. If you want two objects that are "similar" in some fashion to be treated as duplicates, that's when you have to define `__eq__` and `__hash__` (and usually the comparison ops) to make that work.

Answer (score 1):

Your first question is already answered by Pavel Anossov.

But you have another question:

> but how to save order ? Sets not support order. Can i use list instead set for example ?

You *can* use a `list`, but there are a few downsides:

- You get the wrong interface.
- You don't get automatic handling of duplicates. You have to explicitly write `if foo not in res: res.append(foo)`. Obviously, you can wrap this up in a function instead of writing it repeatedly, but it's still extra work.
- It's going to be a lot less efficient if the collection can get large. Basically, adding a new element, checking whether an element already exists, etc. are all going to be O(N) instead of O(1).

What you want is something that works like an ordered `set`. Or, equivalently, like a `list` that doesn't allow duplicates.

If you do all your adds first, and then all your lookups, and you don't need lookups to be fast, you can get around this by first building a `list`, then using `unique_everseen` from the [`itertools` recipes](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes) to remove duplicates.

Or you could just keep a `set` and a `list` or elements by order (or a `list` plus a `set` of elements seen so far). But that can get a bit complicated, so you might want to wrap it up.

Ideally, you want to wrap it up in a type that has exactly the same API as `set`. Something like an `OrderedSet` akin to [`collections.OrderedDict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict).

Fortunately, if you scroll to the bottom of that docs page, you'll see that exactly what you want already exists; there's a link to an [`OrderedSet`](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576694/) recipe at ActiveState.

So, copy it, paste it into your code, then just change `res = set()` to `res = OrderedSet()`, and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can easily do what you want with a list as you asked in your first post since you defined the **eq** operator :

```
l = []
if Test(0) not in l : 
    l.append(Test(0))
```

My 2 cts ...

Answer (score 0):

Pavel Anossov's answer is great for allowing your class to be used in a set with the semantics you want. However, if you want to preserve the order of your items, you'll need a bit more. Here's a function that de-duplicates a list, as long as the list items are hashable:

```
def dedupe(lst):
    seen = set()
    results = []
    for item in lst:
        if item not in seen:
            seen.add(item)
            results.append(item)
    return results
```

A slightly more idiomatic version would be a generator, rather than a function that returns a list. This gets rid of the `results` variable, using `yield` rather than appending the unique values to it. I've also renamed the `lst` parameter to `iterable`, since it will work just as well on any iterable object (such as another generator).

```
def dedupe(iterable):
    seen = set()
    for item in iterable:
        if item not in seen:
            seen.add(item)
            yield item
```

Comment: You don't have to write this yourself; it's already in the [itertools recipes](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes) as `unique_everseen`. Besides being already written, and well tested, and optimized, it also takes a `key` function. So, just copy that to your code and use it, or `pip install more-itertools` and import it from there.